# Shortening file paths using Python

Tags: python, cross-platform, filepath, path-separator

I have an application which should display to the user the path to a file. Let's say the user inputs `/home/me/foo/`, the application should shorten that to `~/foo`.

Is there any way to do this in Python such that it works cross-platform with Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now sure what you are trying to do but changing it to the other format is as simple as:

```
newpath = "~"+filepath[9:]
```

if you want this to work with other usernames,

```
newpath = "~/"+filepath[findfirstindex('foo'):]
```

Comment: Will this work if the user has a much longer or shorter name?

Comment: changed my original answer. you can use findfirstindex to start wherever the first index occurs if there are other usernames